# How do I get a list of routes from a module/directory in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have 3 modules in app folder such as: User Module , Role Module and Permission Module. Also I have different route.php file in each and every module. Now I need to get a route list from User Module.

I got a complete list from all modules using this code:

```
    $routeCollection =Route::getRoutes();  
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        echo $value->getPath()."<br>";
    }
```

Instead of all routes, I want to get a list of routes from a specific module or a specific directory as User Module.

How do I get a list of routes for a specific folder/module/file?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin :: sure I will. I was out of my work for last couple of days. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use same controller in the routes you want to find, you can do something like this:

```
$routeCollection = \Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    $lookFor = 'UserController';
    $controller = $value->getAction();
    $controller = $controller['controller'];

    if (strpos($controller, $lookFor)) {
        echo "This route uses UserController controller ";
    }

    echo $value->getPath()."<br>";
}
```

Well, you got the idea. You can use same approach to search for any other information in `Route::getRoutes()` collection.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to grab all routes which use `UserController`, you can do something like this:

```
$routeCollection = \Route::getRoutes();
$userRoutesArray = [];

foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    $lookFor = 'UserController';
    $controller = $value->getAction();
    if(isset($controller['controller'])){ 
        $controller = $controller['controller'];
    }else{
        continue;
    }

    if (strpos($controller, $lookFor)) {
        array_push($userRoutesArray, $value->getPath();
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate it with `for` or `foreach`.

Comment: I could not understand the line "$controller = $value->getAction()['controller'];" . Would you please elaborate little more ?

Comment: Did you try it? If it doesn't work, try `$action = $value->getAction(); $controller = $action['controller'];`

Comment: Its returning ERROR: "Undefined index: controller" . may I missed something ?     $action = $value->getAction();
            $controller = $action['controller'];

Comment: I've updated code. Also, I've tested it in my own app and it works.

Comment: its getting the same error "Undefined index [controller]" in my controller in the line :  $controller = $controller['controller'];

Comment: If you add `dd($controller);` right before that line, what does it display?

Comment: its returning ::
array:4 [▼
  "uses" => Closure {#98 ▼
    class: "App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider"
    this: RouteServiceProvider {#86 …}
    file: "/Users/selimreza/Sites/entsol/app/Http/routes.php"
    line: "14 to 16"
  }
  "namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers"
  "prefix" => null
  "where" => []
]

Comment: I used this :
$lookFor = 'UserController';
            $controller = $value->getAction();
            dd($controller);

Comment: Are you running this code from a controller or from a function in `routes.php`? Try to change `$controller = $controller['controller'];` to `if (isset($controller['controller'])) { $controller = $controller['controller']; }else{ continue; } `

Comment: I am running this code from my HomeController. now its returning blank page ... means its in else condition

Comment: I use this code `$lookFor = 'UserController';
            if (isset($controller['controller'])) {
                $controller = $controller['controller'];
            }else{
                continue;
            }
            dd($controller);`

Comment: Remove `dd($controller);`, you should use it only for displaying arrays and collections. And now remove it and try to run code again.

Comment: Well, just use some code instead of `echo "This route uses UserController controller ";`. I've updated my post.

Comment: Superb !  Thank you so much again.